# How to get date by string value in IE browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, internet-explorer

I tried to get the date in script side, but in IE is not working and showing invalid date.

my syntax and value is,

`new Date("25-Jul-20")`

Its working in chrome, firefox and other browsers, but except IE

For reference in IE,

[image]

For reference in Chrome,

[image]

Comment: You need to use US or ISO date format for cross-compatibility in most browsers, eg. `new Date('07/25/2020')` or `new Date('2020-07-25')`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - The (unspecified) U.S. date one only works reliably if you use slashes, not dashes: `new Date("07/25/2020")`. (But better to stick to the specified one.)

Comment: You're right - my bad. Corrected.

Comment: For once, I agree with IE. This date format is as confusing as it gets. There's no way to know for sure if you mean 25th of July 2020, or 20th of July 2025. It should also be rejected by Chrome and FF, they are sometimes too indulgent.

Comment: @Ramanan, If you think that the date format I provided in the answer can help to fix the issue then I suggest you please mark the helpful suggestion as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the format you are using for the date is not supported by the IE browser.

This is the reason that you are getting an error for the date in the IE browser.

Below are some format examples that are supported by the IE browser.

```
var a = new Date(2011, 01, 07); // yyyy, mm-1, dd  
var b = new Date(2011, 01, 07, 11, 05, 00); // yyyy, mm-1, dd, hh, mm, ss  
var c = new Date("02/07/2011"); // "mm/dd/yyyy"  
var d = new Date("02/07/2011 11:05:00"); // "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"  
var e = new Date(1297076700000); // milliseconds  
var f = new Date("Mon Feb 07 2011 11:05:00 GMT"); // ""Day Mon dd yyyy hh:mm:ss GMT/UTC
```

Output in the IE 11 browser:

[image]

Reference:

[JavaScript new Date() Returning NaN in IE or Invalid Date in Safari](http://biostall.com/javascript-new-date-returning-nan-in-ie-or-invalid-date-in-safari/)